# Charge distribution on wire cutting flux

Tags: electromagnetism

A straight wire of length $\ell$ moves with a constant velocity, $\vec v,$ through a uniform magnetic field, $\vec B$. The field, the wire and its velocity are at right angles to each other. When a steady state is reached there will be a uniform electric field, $\vec E=-\vec v \times \vec B$ all along the wire, so the free electrons experience no net force.

My question is: assuming that the wire has no net charge, what is the distribution of charge on the surface of the wire that gives rise to this electric field?

Symmetry considerations surely dictate that the surface charge density must be an odd function of displacement from the centre of the rod, but beyond that I haven't made much progress so far.